# VBA User Form does not recognize if function?

Tags: excel, userform, vba

```
Private Sub ROLparameter_Click()
Line1: RolLow = InputBox("Please enter the lower bound percentage for ROL calculation between 0 and 100 (initially " & RolLow * 100 & "%):")

If Not 0 <= RolLow <= 100 Then GoTo Line1
End If

End Sub
```

I have user form button, when I press it will enter this sub. The problem is it gives error "end if without if". When I remove end if, it works strangely.

Such as;

it does recognize the RolLow value when user enter 80, as "80". If not directs it to end sub, if i use only "if" then it will direct to line 1 all the time. No checking of the value.

This code working normally in a module.

What can be the problem?

(Variables are defined public before the subs)

(i tried module.variable thing also)

Comment: try the code in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you are trying to run:
if the user inputs a value smaller than 0 or larger than 100, then go back to *InputBox*

```
Private Sub ROLparameter_Click()

Line1: Rollow = CLng(InputBox("Please enter the lower bound percentage for ROL calculation between 0 and 100 (initially " & Rollow * 100 & "%):"))

If Not ((0 <= Rollow) And (Rollow <= 100)) Then
    GoTo Line1
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `CLng` converts the input (received as String) into Long, you can use also`CInt` if you want for smaller values

Comment: Thanks a lot again!